# Циклическая переадресация https://

Tags: apache, opencart, https

Установил opencart 3.0.2. Получил сертификат для сервера, если принудительно зайти по https://site.ru все работает ок. Когда прописываю в файле .htaccess следующее правило:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

сайт переходит на https но не отображается. **Page not found**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```